# UWP xBind Function used for control visibility not working

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, visual-studio-2022

C#, UWP, VS2022

I have a following xaml

```
<StackPanel  Visibility="{x:Bind WhatIsMyVisibilityState('spRegisterScreen2')}"
x:Name="spRegisterScreen2"  Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" >
```

in code behind

```
public Visibility WhatIsMyVisibilityState(string uiItem)
        {
            Visibility returnValue = Visibility.Collapsed;

 if some condition is == true 
{
             returnValue = Visibility.Visible;
}
...
...
  return returnValue;
}
```

I see that condition is true, and return value is  Visibility.Visible; yet the stackpanel remains in Collapsed state. I wonder what happening.  The trigger point that calls this function is in button click event, at the end of button click I am calling "  this.Bindings.Update(); "  to refresh screen and expect controls to change its visibility state based on logic in WhatIsMyVisibilityState( ) function.

but for some reason, visibility does not change.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

If you want to pass the StackPanel name to the function, you need to pass the StackPanel itself. Then get the name in the function.

Like:

```
public Visibility WhatIsMyVisibilityState(StackPanel uiItem) 
    {
        if (uiItem.Name.Equals("spRegisterScreen2"))
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

    }


 <StackPanel  Visibility="{x:Bind WhatIsMyVisibilityState(spRegisterScreen2)}" x:Name="spRegisterScreen2"
```

---

Please make sure that the parameter inside the  `Visibility="{x:Bind WhatIsMyVisibilityState('spRegisterScreen2')}"` method is a property of the DataContext. Since you are using x:Bind, you have to make sure that your Page have a string property called `spRegisterScreen2`. So the binding expression could find the value of the parameter.

I made a simple demo that you could refer to:

Xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <StackPanel  Visibility="{x:Bind WhatIsMyVisibilityState(Test),Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="spRegisterScreen2" 
                 Background="Red"
                 Width="200" Height="200"
                 Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
  public string Test { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Test = "12";
    }

    public Visibility WhatIsMyVisibilityState(string uiItem) 
    {
        if (uiItem.Equals("12"))
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

    }
```

Comment: x:Bind does call WhatIsMyVisibilityState() function.   spRegisterScreen2 is a name of control and its not the property.  but control name/property has no role here...  I am passing name of control in single quotes 'spRegisterScreen2' so its a string parameter to the function.  if (uiItem.Equals("spRegisterScreen2")) ..  there are more condition checks and finally it returns Visibility state.    Surprisingly the same logic that i have written is working perfectly well in other UWP apps.  , however i am puzzled why this app behaves differently ?

Comment: One difference i just realized is that this UWP app was created using "Template Studio for UWP", however that should not  impact Function Binding , But who knows if i am missing something?

Comment: @Neha Set the StackPanel name as the parameter in the x:Bind throws an error saying 
 **cannot convert from 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel' to 'string'**. It's not correct to do that. You should change the uiItem as StackPanel. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Neha Have you checked my updates?